# Ksoap2 - Multiple Request Parameters

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I have the following soap request xml File:-

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ars="http://www.example.com/ars" xmlns:cbs="http://example2.com/cbs" xmlns:arc="http://example3.com/arc" >
<soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ars:QueryBalanceRequestMsg>
      <RequestHeader>
        <cbs:Version>1</cbs:Version>
        <cbs:MessageSeq>12345</cbs:MessageSeq>
        <cbs:OwnershipInfo>
          <cbs:BEID>xxx</cbs:BEID>
        </cbs:OwnershipInfo>
        <cbs:AccessSecurity>
          <cbs:LoginSystemCode>xxx</cbs:LoginSystemCode>
          <cbs:Password>xxx</cbs:Password>
          <cbs:RemoteIP>127.0.0.1</cbs:RemoteIP>
        </cbs:AccessSecurity>
        <cbs:OperatorInfo>
          <cbs:OperatorID>xxx</cbs:OperatorID>
        </cbs:OperatorInfo>
        <cbs:MsgLanguageCode>xxx</cbs:MsgLanguageCode>
        <cbs:TimeFormat>
           <cbs:TimeType>xxx</cbs:TimeType>
           <cbs:TimeZoneID>xxxx</cbs:TimeZoneID>
        </cbs:TimeFormat>
      </RequestHeader>
      <QueryBalanceRequest>
        <ars:QueryObj>
          <ars:SubAccessCode>
            <arc:PrimaryIdentity>987654321</arc:PrimaryIdentity>
          </ars:SubAccessCode>
        </ars:QueryObj>
      </QueryBalanceRequest>
    </ars:QueryBalanceRequestMsg>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am new to using SOAP, if anyone to tell me how to send this api / or addProperty to ksoap2 library in android.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate from `wsdl` code to (android) java using  `wsdl2code` [here](http://www.wsdl2code.com/pages/example.aspx)

Comment: I don't have the wsdl file, All  I got it above request api provided. I couldnot find any solutions yet to send the above request api using Ksoap2.